# How to implement Search on Firebase data

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of people's and data is coming from firebase as Data stream and I want to search on the people's as user type keyword 'a' it should show all people names start with 'a'.

I have this simple xose.

```
                child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: MainAppService().getProfessionals(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Text('loading...');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('No Professional Found');
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        professionals = snapshot.data.documents;
                      }

                      return buildListView(snapshot, context);
                    })),
```

Comment: You have to use SearchDelegate . Look this example: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/search_demo.dart

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries. The Flutter syntax shouldn't be too different and easy to derive from those Firebase docs, and these Flutter ones: https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html